# Database Error Occured CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Below error message show up on data entry.

Error Number: 1452

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mail_sys_db`.`user_plan_original_item`, CONSTRAINT `user_plan_original_item_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_plan_detail_id`) REFERENCES `user_plan_detail` (`user_plan_detail_id`))

INSERT INTO user_plan_original_item (user_plan_original_item_id,user_plan_detail_id,original_item_id,item_value) VALUES ('1','121','1','a')
```

Answer (score 2):

The error do not have any relation with codeigniter, its a mysql error. Take a look at the following:

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>   central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>   back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>   table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching
>   candidate key value in the parent table.

Means that, you are trying to add a row to your child table for which no matching row is present in parent table.